# Combining pipe with exit status in bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, exit-code

I have this *bash* shell-script command that causes *date* to run if *make* succeeds (terminates with zero exit status) and vice versa:

```
make && date
```

but now I want to process its output e.g.

```
make | sed s/a/A/
```

If I do

```
make | sed s/a/A/ && date
```

*date* runs even when *make* fails.

If I instead do

```
make && date | sed s/a/A/
```

the *sed* processes *date*'s output instead of *make*'s.

Would you know of any solution? Thanks!

---

P.S. I've tried these:

```
(make | sed s/a/A/) && date
```

*date* still runs when *make* fails.

```
(make && (date > /dev/null)) | sed s/a/A/
```

*date* doesn't run when *make* succeeds.

Comment: In the very last case (`(make && (date > /dev/null)) | sed s/a/A/`) date **does** run when make succeeds, but you are sending it's output to a black hole, so it has no effect...

Comment: have a look at [PIPESTATUS](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do have a shell with process substitution (bash does, posix shell is not), than

```
make > >(sed s/a/A/) && date
```

should do the trick, except bash it does not wait for the sed (it seems zsh does, but I only tried it, not checked the doc), so the output of date can get before the last line of sed output. In plain posix shell, you can use a bit more complicated construct

```
((make && date >&3) | sed s/a/A/) 3>&1
```

The date can again run before sed has processed everything, so it's output can again come before the last line of sed output.

If you want the date to only run after the sed has processed everything, your only chance is storing the make status somewhere. Something like:

```
(make && touch make-succeeded) | sed s/a/A/
rm make-succeeded 2>/dev/null && date
```

abusing the fact, that if the file does not exist, rm (without -f) will exit with nonzero status and silencing it's error message with redirection. As Fredrik has mentioned though, bash does in fact have a place where it does stash the exits status, so in bash you can:

```
make | sed s/a/A/
[ 0 -eq $PIPESTATUS[0] ] && date
```

Comment: Thanks! Wish I could give you a bonus point for taking into account that I'd want the date to appear after the sed output.

Answer (score 8):

Turn on `pipefail` in the `make` subshell.

```
(set -o pipefail; make 2>/dev/null | sed s/a/A/) && date
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically like this;

```
my_make () {
  local rc
  make >tmp
  rc=$?
  sed s/a/A/ tmp
  rm tmp
  return $rc
}
```

The temporary file should obviously be handled in a proper way; this is bare-bones in order to focus on the issue at hand. You could probably avoid a temp file altogether if you are clever with file descriptors, but it's Friday and I need more coffee.